# ManyToMany Relation does not create the primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, jpa-2.0

I have a ManyToMany relationship between two classes: ClassA and ClassB, but when the table for this relationship (table called objectA_objectB) there is no primary key on it.

In my ClassA I have the following:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy(value="name")
@JoinTable(name="objectA_objectB",
        joinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="idObjectA", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="idObjectB", referencedColumnName="id")
)
private List<ClassB> objectsB;
```

and in my ClassB I have the reversed relation

```
@ManyToMany
List<ClassA> objectsA;
```

I just want to make a primary key of both id's but I need to change the name of the columns as I do.
Why is the PK missing? How can I define it?

I use JPA 2.0 Hibernate implementation, if this helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are right

I have done the same approach as shown by your question. And, indeed, Hibernate does not generate its **composite** primary key as expected.

So if you want to generate its composite primary key, you should split your @ManyToMany into @OneToMany-@ManyToOne relationship. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212058/how-to-make-a-composite-primary-key-java-persistence-annotation/1252317#1252317) how to...

**UPDATE**

When you have a bi-directional relationship, you must set up the inverse side of the relationship by using mappedBy attribute

```
// ClassA

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="objectA_objectB",
    joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="idObjectA", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="idObjectB", referencedColumnName="id")
)
private List<ClassB> objectsB;
```

...

```
// ClassB

// You do not specify the foreign key column here (it is mapped by the other side)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="objectsB")
List<ClassA> objectsA;
```

mappedBy="objectsB" says

> See whether objectsB property in ClassA contains me and, if so, save our relationship in objectA_objectB table

Comment: @Arthur Ronald F D Garcia It still happen the same with mappedBy