# ManyToMany relationship using JPA with Hibernate provider is not creating primary keys

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, many-to-many, primary-key

I've created two JPA entities (Client, InstrumentTraded) using Hibernate as a provider that have a ManyToMany relationship.  After letting Hibernate generate the tables for MySQL it appears that the ManyToMany relationship table does not contain primary keys for the two foreign keys.  This allows duplicate records in the many-to-many table, which is not the desired result.

**Tables generated:**

```
client(id,name)  
instrument_traded(id,name)  
client_instrument_traded(FK client_id, FK instrument_traded_id)
```

**Preferred table:**

```
client_instrument_traded(PK,FK client_id, PK,FK instrument_traded_id)
```

**Entities:**

```
@Entity
public class Client extends AbstractEntity<Integer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 125)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "instrument_traded_id")}, uniqueConstraints =
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_client_instruments_traded_client_id_instrument_traded_id",
    columnNames = {"client_id", "instrument_traded_id"}))
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_client_instruments_traded_client_id",
    inverseName = "FK_client_instruments_traded_instrument_traded_id")
    private List<InstrumentTraded> instrumentsTraded;

    public Client() {
    }

    public List<InstrumentTraded> getInstrumentsTraded() {
        return instrumentsTraded;
    }

    public void setInstrumentsTraded(List<InstrumentTraded> instrumentsTraded) {
        this.instrumentsTraded = instrumentsTraded;
    }

    ...
}



@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_instrument_traded_name", columnNames = {"name"})})
public class InstrumentTraded extends AbstractEntity<Integer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "instrumentsTraded", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Client> clients;

    public InstrumentTraded() {
    }

    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }

    public void setClients(List<Client> clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    ...

}
```

After doing some research it looks like the only solution is for [mapping a join table with additional columns](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns) using `@OneToMany` `@IdClass` and a composite primary key class when I don't need additional columns.  Is this the only solution besides the one I've included in the code above, which is using a `@UniqueConstraint` with the two foreign key columns on the `@ManyToMany` mapping?  It seems a bit ridiculous the amount of work needed for a common scenario like this.  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212058/how-to-make-a-composite-primary-key-java-persistence-annotation/6344626#6344626

Comment: Also worths to check if you accidently didn't add a record twice, this happened to me, so `list.add(x); list.add(x);` results duplicate in lists.

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar problem. All I did was that I changed the collection type from List to Set:

```
private List<InstrumentTraded> instrumentsTraded;
```

to

```
private Set<InstrumentTraded> instrumentsTraded;
```

And somehow Hibernate now generates primary keys for the join table.

Comment: "All the great things are simple..."

Comment: Does it? Or is it just the Java Set doing its work on memory?

Comment: Also worths to check if you accidently didn't add a record twice, this happened to me, so `list.add(x); list.add(x);` results duplicate in lists.

Comment: @ViniciusPires, it really creates a composite primary key! Tested.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to solve the problem:

Client.java:

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinTable(
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "instrument_traded_id")},
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(
            columnNames = {"client_id", "instrument_traded_id"})}
)
 private List<InstrumentTraded> instrumentsTraded;
```

This is for unidirectional mapping. If you want a bidirectional relationship, change the mapping in `InstrumentTraded.class` to the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your mapping looks odd (in particular the `joinColumn` part of the `@JoinTable` annotation). I would expect something like this:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
    joinColumns= 
        @JoinColumn(name="CLIENT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"), 
    inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="instrument_traded_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
    uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(
            name="UK_client_instruments_traded_client_id_instrument_traded_id",
            columnNames = {"client_id", "instrument_traded_id"}
        )
)
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_client_instruments_traded_client_id",
inverseName = "FK_client_instruments_traded_instrument_traded_id")
private List<InstrumentTraded> instrumentsTraded;
```

But unless you want to override the defaults (and I guess you do), I would just skip the `@JoinTable`.

Comment: I do want to override the defaults because it pluralizes the the instrument_traded_id (instruments_traded_id).  I have a custom naming strategy that adds "_id" if it "_id" doesn't exist on the end of a foreign key.  I can remove the joinColumns=@JoinColumn.  Do you have a working example of a ManyToMany creating a primary key consisting of two foreign keys in the ManyToMany table?

Comment: @dukethrash: `Do you have a working example of a ManyToMany creating a primary key consisting of two foreign keys in the ManyToMany table?` That's the default behavior if properly annotated. Did you try without the `joinColumn` (or with the above one)?

Comment: Yes I tried yours (with the exception that referencedColumn is actually referencedColumnName) and it is still not generating the primary keys.  I've even added the following on InstrumentTraded just to see if that would change anything.

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "instrumentsTraded")
    private List<Client> clients;

Answer (score 0):

**Or** Split your @ManyToMany into @OneToMany - @ManyToOne relationship See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212058/how-to-make-a-composite-primary-key-java-persistence-annotation/1252317#1252317) how you can accomplish this mapping