# JPA and Hibernate initialize Non Lazy Collections Error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

In my JavaFX application When I use **Non Lazy Collection** option with EmbeddedId class, for maintain bidirectional relation ship it will produce following exception. After working on several hours yet I can not get fixed it. Entity classes as follow. Thanks.

**EmbeddedId class**

```
@Embeddable
public class WorkflowStepPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "STEP_SEQ_NO", nullable = false)
    private Integer stepSeqNo;

    @JoinColumn(name = "WST_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private WfScriptTemplate wfScriptTemplate;
}
```

**WorkflowStep Entity** (with EmbeddedId)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workflow_step")
public class WorkflowStep implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private WorkflowStepPK id;

    // more fields
}
```

**WfScriptTemplate Entity** (with bidirectional relation ship)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wf_script_template")
public class WfScriptTemplate implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    // Refer the filed "wfScriptTemplate" inside the Composite key of WorkflowStep entity
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "id.wfScriptTemplate")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OrderBy(value = "stepSeqNo")
    private List<WorkflowStep> workflowStepList;
}
```

**Exception on postgresql**

```
  Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitial
izer.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventList
ener.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1893)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:668)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:885)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:359)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:251)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(Reposito
ryFactorySupport.java:344)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactory
Support.java:329)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java
:136)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column workflowst0_.stepseqno does not exist
  Position: 2741
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
        ... 108 more
```

**Exception on MySQL**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitial
izer.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventList
ener.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1893)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:668)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:885)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:359)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:330)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(Reposito
ryFactorySupport.java:344)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactory
Support.java:329)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java
:136)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'workflowst0_.stepSeqNo' in 'order clause'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2313)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
        ... 107 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from JPA 2.0 Specification, chapter 11.1.38 OrderBy Annotation:

> The dot (".") notation is used to refer to an attribute within an
>   embedded attribute. The value of each identifier used with the dot
>   notation is the nameof the respective embedded field or property.

so you should rather annotate `workflowStepList` with:

```java
@OrderBy(value = "id.stepSeqNo")
private List<WorkflowStep> workflowStepList;
```

thus indicating that `stepSeqNo` belongs to `WorkflowStep` embeddable.