# Java DB: bind multiple instances of a class to one instance of another class

Tags: java, javadb

I don't really know how to describe this problem (as you tell by the dodgy title), so here's a full description of the problem.
I have two classes, Teacher and Class.
Each teacher can teach to several classes and each class has several teachers.
In Java, we've mapped it like this:

```
public class Class {
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "classes")
private List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

We have a superclass, User, and two subclasses, Teacher and Student. These classes inherit from the User superclass. So, in our database we have a table called Users which stores all users as teachers or students.
Now, students can only be in one class, so they can only have one ClassID stored in the database.
But as I said before, teachers can have several classes. So the point is : How am I able to store all the classes that a teacher has in the database?
I see Java created an extra table, called User_Class, which is probably ment to store all the different classes a teacher has and vica versa. Problem is that I can't find any documentation about how to work with this.

Can someone please give me a hand here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to solve this by code, I think you need to understand it from the database point of view.

You are trying to build a many-to-many relationship. This sort of relationship is built by splitting it in two one-to-many relationships.

So, if you have two entities (namely `Course` and `Teacher`... I avoid using "classes" to prevent confusion), and one `Course` can have many `Teacher`s and one `Teacher` can have many `Course`s, then a way to create the relation (in the database) would be like this:

**Table `Courses`**

```
courseId     (PK)
courseName
```

**Table `Teachers`**

```
teacherId    (PK)
teacherName
```

**Table `Courses_Teachers`**

```
courseId    (FK, PK)
teacherId   (FK, PK)
```

(`PK` stands for "primary key", and `FK` stands for "foreign key")

Hope this little introduction helps you visualize the way to solve your problem.

Comment: This confirms the way I was thinking and that my database's setup is right. I have a table teachers and  courses, and a table teachers_courses. But I don't know how to assign multiple courses to one teacher through Java and JSON..

Comment: Split the process in steps: First add the teachers and the courses, and then relate them by adding records to the "courses_teachers" table that hold the ids of both the course and the teacher

Comment: Can this be done with java code? Or do I have to do this with SQL
Because I want to be able to let user adjust these relations by themselves.

Comment: I would use SQL... but that's only me... if you want (and/or can) use a different approach, you are free to do so

Answer (score 0):

That approach is based on a composite primary key.
This link is about that:
[how to make a composite primary key (java persistence annotation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212058/how-to-make-a-composite-primary-key-java-persistence-annotation)